# How to find out if dx debug layer is available?

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11

Is there a possibility to find out if the dx debug layer is available before creating a device with the [D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag?

I am using Direct3D 11 (and C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you must have `D3D11*SDKLayers.dll` installed; otherwise, device creation fails.

So, method 1: check if D3D11*SDKLayers.dll exist.

Method 2: go ahead and try to create a device with the debug flag. If fails, remove the debug flag and try again.